# Google App Engine Faceted Search in production has to be enabled / activated?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, faceted-search

I've just created locally on my machine a perfectly running faceted search service using Google App Engine Faceted Search, written in Python.
As soon as I deploy to our production server, it throws an error during the index creation, specifically when the code try to execute **index.put(docs)**, where docs is an array of [max 100] **search.Document**.

The error is: "**PutError: one or more put document operations failed: Value is empty**"

I tried then to step back to the the previous version of my service, which was working like a charm until then. I removed all the new **search.TextField** added and I removed the **facets=[search.AtomFacet(...)]** from the **search.Document** constructor keywords.
It started working again.

Then, baby step forward again, I've added all the fields I needed, but still no facets=[] in the constructor. It worked.
As soon as I added again **facets=[search.AtomFacet(name='propName', value=doc.propName if doc.propName else '')]** then the error appeared again. Whilst locally on my machine, it works perfectly.

Is there any setting / configuration we need to enable on production server to have this feature?

Thank you

Comment: Do you have billing activated? Search doesn't have free quotas i believe.

Comment: Yes, we do have billing enabled.

Comment: Exactly, it's only the faceted search that doesn't seem to work, we already use search api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facet value cannot be empty string. You can workaround it by not including facets with empty values or have a special value for your empty facets. The local implementation of faceted search (python) currently accepts empty facets that is a bug and will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I received an answer directly from the google team, which is:

> Facet value cannot be empty string. You can workaround this by not
>   including facets with empty values or have a special value for your
>   empty facets (not recommended as empty facets normally means that
>   document does not belong to the specified category/facet, so it should
>   not be counted in aggregation of that facet). The local implementation
>   of faceted search (python) currently accepts empty facets that is a
>   bug and will be fixed.

From [this thread](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log&groupby=&sort=&id=6695) for who might be interested in following the conversation.